# Having problems with Sleep() func on MouseMoveRelative on LUA

Tags: lua, mouse, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

got a new drive and installed a fresh windows.

Before on old OS, i could use "Sleep" to make "MoveMouseRelative" work like it was natural movement.

i have created a function were i can move the mouse calling it with how many times i want it to "move"

and with the milliseconds between each "move" Example:(works well)

```
function _move(x, range, time, range2)
    for i = 1, x do
    MoveMouseRelative(range,range2)
    Sleep(time)
    end
end
```

n

If i set "Sleep(1)" beteween each "MoveMouseRelative" it moves like it has like "Sleep(50)", i couldnt figure why.

if i call it with 50 Moves of 1ms it takes 2,5 seconds to finish instead of 50ms

on my old drive with the old OS install(same PC), i can use it normally takes 50ms

Its like the software wont let me use small ms such as 1 ms.

Tried

LGHUB Reinstall

deactivating AV

disabling things on windows,

copying the LGHUB folder from the OS that is working well

copying the LGHUB folder with the configs(LocalAppdata)

My Mouse is the G502 SE

Help?

Comment: Fix `time=30ms` and tune `range` to set the mouse movement speed you need.  30ms gives you refresh rate of about 30Hz, you don't need it faster.

Comment: You should not use `Sleep(1)`, it is very unstable. It depends not only from Windows version, but also from CPU load. Redesign your program to use only delays which are multiple of 30ms. ("time slice" in Windows is either 10ms or 15ms)

Comment: Thing is, "MouseMoveRelative" in the LUA integrated to Logitech GHUB is limited to move 127 units per call(-127 to 127), then to make it smooth i have to call it multiple times, wich worked well for about two years(even with some OS reinstall), anything higher than 10ms makes it look "laggy" and not natural.

what i dont get it, if i boot into the old OS, that is on the HDD, it works ok,  and not on the new OS install. what could be causing interference?

Comment: `anything higher than 10ms makes it look "laggy"` - it's hard to believe that you really need 100Hz refresh rate of mouse cursor movement.  Consider changing your nickname to "eagle_eye" :-)

Comment: `if i boot into the old OS, that is on the HDD, it works ok, and not on the new OS install` - do you have two different releases of Win10?

Comment: They are on different drives, they should be the same, as they are updated to the same version, and use the same hardware, one is SSD(new) and the other is HDD(old) my last SSD died, this one is an replacement.

Comment: yea, use the last function listed  --  http://lua-users.org/wiki/SleepFunction  --  I've had better results with that os.clock() method

Comment: @Doyousketch2 it wont work, as the Logitech LUA is limited, and we dont have that function avaliable.

Ill try to reinstall windows again,but i will not use the updated windows installation that i have on a stick, and this time before updating i will install LGHUB first, as this is the only thing i did different. May i have luck this time i hope.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff so i did a complete reinstall with old windows 10 ISO, got it to work again, but only with the LGHub open, when it is on the tray, it does not work(slow). i simply give up. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR:
`Sleep(1)` behavior is unstable and should not be used.
`Sleep()` has a much worse precision than you think it has.

---

Long answer:

`Sleep()` in LGHUB script internally invokes WinAPI function [`Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep).

An excerpt from the documentations:

> After the sleep interval has passed, the thread is ready to run. Note that a ready thread is not guaranteed to run immediately. Consequently, the thread may not run until some time after the sleep interval elapses.

> The system clock "ticks" at a constant rate. If dwMilliseconds is less than the resolution of the system clock, the thread may sleep for less than the specified length of time. If dwMilliseconds is greater than one tick but less than two, the wait can be anywhere between one and two ticks, and so on.

The "tick" here is the "time slice" length which is 15ms on my Windows (but it could be 10ms on another Windows versions).

As you see from the documentation above, the `Sleep()` function has precision of one "tick", so behavior of `Sleep(1)` is unstable by design.