# Logitech Lua Sleep Behavior

Tags: lua, mouse, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

Since Egor always help, this is intended to show him the problem, but if you know how to solve, please help too!

https://youtu.be/J2vRfnUplio <<< this is how the script should work. (look at the descripition for more info)

https://youtu.be/HH_MmfXUdl8 <<< This is how it doing now, at windows newer versions.

[Having problems with Sleep() func on MouseMoveRelative on LUA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64564344/having-problems-with-sleep-func-on-mousemoverelative-on-lua)

^^ This is the last question that shows the problem and you helped me there

GHUB has the same version on both, so isnt GHUB the problem.

Sleep(1) wont behave like it should, my best guess is that windows changed something but WHAT is the question.

Someone help?

Comment: You should avoid using `Sleep(1)`.  Its behavior depends on Windows version, number of CPU cores and total CPU load.  `Sleep` has 15 ms precision.  And you never really need 1 ms precision when simulating mouse movement.  The solution to your problem is to recalculate the mouse trajectory using 30 ms time intervals and use `Sleep(30)` in your code.  To make mouse move faster increase `dx` and `dy` instead of decreasing `delay`.

Comment: You was just lucky enough with `Sleep(1)` in the previous Windows versions.  Do not rely on luck.  Write robust and stable code.

Comment: But i need the code to be that way, Else it would be too slow, or without the sleep("sleep(0)")  it gets really snappy

if i could i would use it with higher sleep() ms. its a windows setting that changed i just have to figure it out. 
i have reached Logitech devs but they are taking too long to answer, and last time they just sent me an auto msg with some generic actions, like they hadnt read what i sent them.

Comment: Please post your program which really needs 1 ms delay.  I'll help you to modify it to 30 ms intervals without losing visual quality.  Your monitor displays new frame every 16 ms (in 60 FPS game).   You don't need to refresh mouse cursor more frequently than once per 16 ms.

Comment: `Sleep(1)` actually means "wait from 0 to 15 ms, IDK how long exactly".  It is not suitable for simulating mouse movement.

Comment: My display does 144hz, and i can run the game fine at 144 fps, but thats not the problem, the problem is that the now the Script looks robotic. you can see the diference, with 1 ms moving with MouseMoveRelative. i need it to be moving like im swiping the mouse. the way it does with 30 ms its like im poking the mouse multiple times...

Comment: you can make that spin wich is in your script example look fast and smooth?
>> Template script file for Logitech Gaming Software << this one
so i can study it?

Comment: In my script example `Sleep()` is equivalent to `Sleep(5)`, and this is unstable.  Replace `Sleep()` with `Sleep(15)` and replace `90` with `30` in both `for j = 1, 90` and `(j / 90)`.  That should be fast and look smooth (it's the smoothest you can get from G-Hub).

Comment: that does not look natural at all. Guess ill have to make an new partition and use the winver 1511 all the times i need the script to run things at 1 ms. Until i find what is changed, that i cant use it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the following block of code at the beginning of your script, before `OnEvent()` function

```
do
   local function busyloop(final_ctr)
      final_ctr = final_ctr - final_ctr%1
      local ctr, prev_ms, ms0, ctr0 = 0
      while ctr ~= final_ctr do
         local ms = GetRunningTime()
         if prev_ms and ms ~= prev_ms then
            if not ms0 then
               ms0, ctr0 = ms, ctr
            elseif final_ctr < 0 and ms - ms0 > 500 then
               return (ctr - ctr0) / (ms - ms0)
            end
         end
         prev_ms = ms
         ctr = ctr + 1
      end
   end
   local coefficient = busyloop(-1)
   function FastSleep(ms)
      return busyloop(ms * coefficient)
   end
end
```

After that you can use function `FastSleep(delay)` in your script for small time intervals.

Example:

```
FastSleep(0.5)  -- wait for 0.5 ms
```

For big time intervals (for example, 30 ms or more) standard `Sleep()` is preferred.

Comment: WOW, thats a new level of AWESOMENESS! Egor, i wish you all the best things, you ROCK, that is working just fine.

i can use my scripts again like it was before.

Comment: @ALWD - This block of code should be placed BEFORE the beginning of `OnEvent` function.  You have inserted it inside `OnEvent()` body, so the delay appears.