# Logitech lua reliable Sleep

Tags: windows, lua, macros, sleep, logitech-gaming-software

**Introduction**

I am writing a lua script for my logitech mouse. The logitech lua api has [this](https://douile.github.io/logitech-toggle-keys/APIDocs.pdf) documentation.

My script moves the mouse every x milliseconds to draw a pattern. My problem is that the Sleep(x) function of this lua api is very inaccurate. I have read that it takes time (couple milliseconds) for it to get a thread, so that time adds to the execution time for the code itself. However it makes it useless for measuring milliseconds.

**Question**

Do you know a workaround? Is there a more capable way for measuring milliseconds than the Sleep(x) function?

Also I wanted to note that in windows 10 version 1909 and bellow, it was much-much more accurate. They have messed something with it so it is inaccurate since windows 10 version 2004 (aruound august, last year). So I would need to find a workaround for this.

**My Code**

Here is a snippet from my code:

```
PressMouseButton(1)
--1
MoveMouseRelative(-26, 36)
Sleep(127)
--2
MoveMouseRelative(2, 36)
Sleep(127)
--3
MoveMouseRelative(-36, 32)
Sleep(127)
--4
MoveMouseRelative(-33, 30)
Sleep(127)
--5
MoveMouseRelative(-11, 38)
Sleep(127)
ReleaseMouseButton(1)
```

This does not work on its own, but you can see here how I want to use the function.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: why do you need millisecond accuracy here in the first place?

Comment: [Sleep with better precision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65356366/1847592)

Answer (score 1):

`Sleep` is not for measuring milliseconds. It pauses your script for a certain amount of time.

From what I can see it is not possible to load any libraries from a Logitech script.

So you can only use `Sleep` or run a loop to delay.

Comment: Hi,
First of all, thank you for your answer!
So i think i was unclear, i do not want it to measure time. I need the function to stop my program for an exact time, measured in milliseconds. As I see now this function is not accurate enough for this purpose.
when you say "run a loop to delay" what do you mean exactly? can you show a code example for this?
Thank you for your time

Comment: well delays are usually implemented using loops. the more loop cycles, the longer it takes to execute. that way you could implement your own delay function and tune it. but in general you shouldn't expect ms accuracy in an application like that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Send you a logitech high-precision delay, accurate to 1ms, why high precision, because win10 1909 after the system version, logitech script 1ms=15.6ms, so need

```
function Sleep3(time)
    local a = GetRunningTime()
    while GetRunningTime()-a < time do
    end
end
```