# Logitech Lua script for high precision sleep

Tags: lua, sleep, logitech-gaming-software

This is my attempt to make a Logitech high-precision delay, accurate to 1ms.
Why do you need high precision delay?  Because starting with Win10 release 2004, Logitech `Sleep(1)` is actually sleeps for 15.6ms, so you might need a more precise `Sleep()` to preserve the original (Win10 1909) behavior of your old scripts.

```
function Sleep3(time)
    local a = GetRunningTime()
    while GetRunningTime()-a < time do
    end
end
```

Is `Sleep3()` accuracy really equals to 1ms?

Comment: the button you clicked to create this post is labelled Ask Question. why would you click it to not ask a qeuestion? if you want so share a solution to a common problem post a question and an answer please. you should also explain how you verified that this is actually true

Comment: Even if this works, it's a busy sleep and you most likely do not want this in mouse scrips as they are often used for games, where you need the CPU time.

Comment: You also answered here already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66154875/logitech-lua-reliable-sleep so I personally consider this question as a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

Logitech `GetRunningTime()` just invokes WinAPI function [GetTickCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-gettickcount)
As you can see from the doc,

> The resolution of the GetTickCount function is limited to the resolution of the system timer, which is typically in the range of 10 milliseconds to 16 milliseconds

In other words, the values returned by `GetRunningTime()` are not sequential integers.
When you call `GetRunningTime()` in a loop, you will receive something like the following:
0,0,0,...,0,15,15,15,...,15,31,31,..,31,46,46,...
This means it is unable to make 1ms-precision delay by using `GetRunningTime()`.
The actual precision of `Sleep3()` is 15ms, as usual `Sleep()` has.

Comment: function OnEvent(event,arg)
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4 then
        a = GetRunningTime()
        for i = 1,1000,1 do
            Sleep(1)
        end
        OutputLogMessage((GetRunningTime() - a) / 1000)
    end
end

Comment: @logit_lua - What is the output of your script on your PC?

Comment: 1.89 1.86 1.82 ...

Comment: And what is the output for the following script? `function OnEvent(event,arg)
 if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4 then 
 local prev
 for i = 1,1000,1 do 
 Sleep(1) 
 local this = GetRunningTime()
 if prev and this ~= prev then
 OutputLogMessage(this-prev.." ") 
 end
 prev = this
 end 
 end 
 end`

Answer (score -1):

```
function OnEvent(event,arg)
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4 then
        a = GetRunningTime()
        for i = 1,1000,1 do
            Sleep(1)
        end
        OutputLogMessage((GetRunningTime() - a) / 1000)
    end
end
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: I already explained the title