# Logitech Lua Script: MoveMouseRelative not working as expected

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I am trying to write a script which will spin my character 180 degrees in game while holding lctrl and right clicking. This script works, but takes forever to spin around because of the sleep timer:

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 2 and IsModifierPressed("lctrl")) then
        for i = 0, 96 do
            MoveMouseRelative (125,0)
            Sleep (1)
        end
    end
end
```

If I increase MouseMoveRelative beyond 125, it starts to move the mouse in the wrong direction. No matter what value I use (I've tried lots of values between 100 and 12,000), it always moves the mouse a very small distance either left or right.

If I eliminate the Sleep function, the results are inconsistent. It usually rotates my character between 80-140 degrees. I suspect this is because MoveMouseRelative starts by getting the current mouse position and it requires a delay before the position it gets is accurate.

Any guidance as to why MouseMoveRelative doesn't work correctly for values above 125? Or any advice on how to quickly move the mouse 12,000 relative units on the x-axis instantaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I increase MouseMoveRelative beyond 125, it starts to move the mouse in the wrong direction.

The allowed range is `-127...+127`

> I suspect this is because MoveMouseRelative starts by getting the current mouse position

No.
It does not ask the current mouse position.
It invokes `SendInput()` without flag `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` to simulate relative mouse movement.

> how to quickly move the mouse 12,000 relative units on the x-axis instantaneously?

```
for i = 0, 96 do
    MoveMouseRelative (125,0)
end
```

> If I eliminate the Sleep function, the results are inconsistent. It usually rotates my character between 80-140 degrees.

Try [more precise version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65361749/1847592) of `Sleep()`

```
for i = 0, 96 do
    MoveMouseRelative (125,0)
    FastSleep(1)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> Or any advice on how to quickly move the mouse 12,000 relative units
> on the x-axis instantaneously?

If you want to move relative 12000 instantaneously, why do you move 97 steps of 125 with 1ms delays?

97*125 is 12125

Why not `MoveMouseRelative(12125, 0)` ?

According to the manual MoveMouseRelative takes "a few milliseconds" to complete.
1 ms is not a few. Reading the mouse position too early will give you the starting position. So I would presume that spamming relative movements which refer to that position might cause problems.

Comment: I am indeed doing 96 steps of 125 with 1ms delays, see above. It works, but its really slow.

MoveMouseRelative(12125,0) only seems to move the position a few degrees. It doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @user2238685 0-96 is 97 steps.